# Generate Matlab Plot to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matlab, plot, jupyter-notebook, matlab-engine

- When i run this code to python notebook, generates a plot in
  MATLAB correctly based on the condition i have assign.
- I will like to display it to the python notebook and not in the matlab.

  ```
   import matlab.engine
   m = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
   m.addpath(r'C:\Users\AN\Desktop\MATLAB',nargout=0)
   m.function(100)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by saving the figure to image and upload it to the directory of jypiter where is called using from IPython import display library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).